# Using Lagrange multipliers to maximize function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Use Lagrange multipliers to maximize function

$$f(x,y)=6xy,$$

subject to the constraint

$$2x+3y=24.$$

$$F(x,y,\lambda)=6xy+\lambda(2x+3y-24)$$

$$F_{x}=6y+2\lambda=0$$

$$F_{y}=6x+3\lambda=0$$

$$y = - \frac{1}{3} \lambda$$

$$x = - \frac{1}{2} \lambda$$

$$\frac{3}{2}y= - \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{3}{2} \right) \lambda = - \frac{1}{2} \lambda=x$$

I'm not sure where the $(3y)/2$ came from. Can someone help me with this? I know what to do after. Thank you so much.

Comment: I did...Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: $y = -1/3\lambda$ so $\lambda = -3y$. Then, using $x=-1/2\lambda$, we get $x=(-1/2)(-3y)=3/2y$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did it the wrong way I guess by setting -3y=-2x and solving for x. Thanks again for the help and not being a d.

Comment: No pro would use Lagrange in this case since $f(x)=2x(24-2x)$ ...

Comment: Usually one should get rid of $\lambda$ asap.

Answer (score 3):

You found $x=-\lambda/2$ and $y=-\lambda/3$. Now plug this into the constraint and obtain
$$24=2x+3y=-\lambda-3\lambda\ .$$
It follows that necessarily $\lambda=-6$, so that you obtain $x=3$, $\>y=2$. So there is a unique conditionally stationary point $P=(3,2)$.

In order to show that  $f(P)=36$ is indeed the global maximum of $f$ for the given constraint some qualitative argument is needed. In this regard note that $f$ is negative in the second and fourth quadrants, and that there are no points fulfilling the constraint in the third quadrant. Therefore it's all about the segment connecting the points $(0,8)$ and $(12,0)$. There is a unique hyperbola $6xy={\rm const.}$ touching this segment, and the corresponding constant $(=36)$ realizes the $\max$ of $f$ under the constraint.